# The Gods Are Word-Crazy: Condensed and Corrected

Tags: wordplay, poetry, anagram

A secret word that Hera found
Pan scattered, just for fun.
Your quest: restore the severed parts
Then celebrate. You're done.
But should you seek the letters here
By Zeus, you'll not get one!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Gods Are Word-Crazy!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/the-gods-are-word-crazy)

Comment: You could've just edited it.

Comment: @Deusovi Maybe he should just delete the original...

Comment: @Deusovi It doesn't make sense to close this as a duplicate of the other when by the author's own admission the other one was flawed.  Why not VTC the original instead? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643

Comment: I agree with @GentlePurpleRain (shock, I know) (though it does pain me to see the one answer on the other one go away)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: Good call! I always forgot that you can close duplicates in the "wrong" order. I'll retract my close vote here and VTC the other.

Comment: Closing the original sounds right. I'd vote for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This version made the hint a little more obvious.

> There are three letters that don't appear at all in the poem:  **I, M, X**.
>
>   Anagramming these, we get **MIX**.

Comment: I even tried this with the original version and only got the MX, so discarded the idea... :\